# Design Pattern for Prompting Users after DML occurs, then performing DDLs?

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to write a PLSQL script that I can run from SQLPlus that would perform, in general, something like the following:

1. Perform some DML actions on a few tables.
2. Prompt to user to confirm the actions taken in Step 1.
3. Upon confirmation, perform a commit and a series of DDL actions, otherwise rollback.

Ideally, I want to reduce the manual input required by the user and ideally have the script do all of the work (including commit/rollback when the user specifies and rollback when errors occur).

I have tried the following:

1. Separate the DML and DDL into their own PLSQL blocks.

   Issues:

   - If there is an error in the DML block, the DDL block still executes.
   - Cannot handle custom errors I raise cleanly at the SQLPlus interface (i.e. It just produces the big ORA error message and I would prefer to catch that and just display a custom string message).
2. Wrap the separate blocks in a single error-handling block.

   Issues:

   - Lose the ability to prompt for user input.

I can't be the first person that wants to perform DDL actions conditioned on user input following a DML change. Is there an established pattern for trying to perform this sequence of operations or is this something the language just can't do?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably you could keep the two-block structure, but have the second block do nothing if some host variable is not set by the first block. I'm not sure what these custom errors that you raise in SQL\*Plus are, though.

Comment: PLSQL / SQL* Plus is not good at emulating  user interface programs and you should prefer any other language to get a better control of such actions.

Comment: Hey William, what I meant by "cleanly" is that I want to catch the error and just display a custom message, rather than the cumbersome ORA-error message block.

How can I reference a variable from a separate anonymous block from within another?

Comment: You could wrap a PL/SQL block with an exception handler wherein you can convert the ugly ORA error message with your own (perhaps less ugly) error message using raise_application_error; but I agree with Kaushik, this is a task perhaps not best suited to a command-line tool like SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should look to a scripting language to implement complex interactive logic, but one way to pass information between two separate blocks in SQL*Plus is to use a host variable:

```
set serverout on size 10000
set autoprint off
set feedback off

var status number

begin
    update sometable set somecolumn = 1
    where  whatever = somethingelse;

    :status := 1;
end;
/

begin
    if :status = 1 then
        dbms_output.put_line('The update worked.');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Something went wrong.');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Output:

```
    update sometable set somecolumn = 1
           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


Something went wrong.
```